# Irvine32 library on emu8086 emulator

Tags: assembly, emu8086, irvine16

Is there a way to get the Irvine library on emu8086 if so please let me know how to because i tried to get it on there by pasting the contents of the lib in the emu8086 folder but i am still getting an error.

Comment: It's difficult for people to help without knowing what error you get.

Comment: @ThomasJager Basically im asking how do you install the irvine lib for emu8086

Comment: You can't use Irvine **32** on emu8086; emu8086 emulates an 8086, not an 80386, so it doesn't support 32-bit registers or instructions.  That's why I tagged your question Irvine16, because that 16-bit version of the Irvine library might work.